# There is an issue where a rectangle is drawn when hovered over regardless of the mouseEvent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

```
const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);

 const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const startX = useRef(null);
  const startY = useRef(null);
  const canvasOffSetX = useRef(null);
  const canvasOffSetY = useRef(null);

  const contextRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = videoRef.current.clientWidth;

    canvas.height = videoRef.current.clientHeight;
    contextRef.current = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const handleMouseMove = event => {
      if (isDrawing) drawRectangle(event);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [isDrawing]);

  const startDrawingRectangle = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    nativeEvent.preventDefault();
    nativeEvent.stopPropagation();

    startX.current = nativeEvent.clientX - canvasOffSetX.current;
    startY.current = nativeEvent.clientY - canvasOffSetY.current;

    setIsDrawing(true);
  };

  const drawRectangle = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (!isDrawing) return;

    const rect = videoRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const context = contextRef.current;

    if (context) {
      const newMouseX = nativeEvent.clientX - canvasOffSetX.current;
      const newMouseY = nativeEvent.clientY - canvasOffSetY.current;

      // const rectWidth = newMouseX - startX.current;
      // const rectHeight = newMouseY - startY.current;

      const xtl = Math.min(startX.current, newMouseX);
      const ytl = Math.min(startY.current, newMouseY);
      const xbr = Math.max(startX.current, newMouseX);
      const ybr = Math.max(startY.current, newMouseY);

      const rectWidth = xbr - xtl;
      const rectHeight = ybr - ytl;

      // contextRef.current.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);
      // contextRef.current.strokeRect(startX.current + rect.left, startY.current + rect.top, rectWidth, rectHeight);

      contextRef.current.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);
      contextRef.current.strokeRect(xtl + rect.left, ytl + rect.top, rectWidth, rectHeight);

      // console.log(`xtl: ${xtl}, ytl: ${ytl}, xbr: ${xbr}, ybr: ${ybr}`);
    }
  };

  const stopDrawingRectangle = () => {
    // setIsDrawing(false);
    startX.current = null;
    startY.current = null;
  };
```

I've tried replacing mouseEvent with `mousemove` or `click` inside useEffect, shutting down the app, turning it back on, and then running it, and I get the same issue.
What I want is for the rectangle to only be drawn when the mouse is **clicked** and for the rectangle to disappear when the mouse cursor is out of range of the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Where do you call `startDrawingRectangle`?

Comment: @Geshode I am calling the onMouseDown handler inside the video element.
Also, drawRectangle behaves as onMouseLeave and stopDrawingRectangle as onMouseLeave.

I change to 'mousedown' in useEffect. still, Just hovering without clicking the mouse will draw a rectangl